# How to view data from the server api on ejs files- sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am completely new to Sails.js and to node.js. I have created myself a simple API using the blueprint address bar feature so I currently got on localhost:1337/user something like this:
`[
  {
    "name": "Jonh",
    "createdAt": "2014-10-09T18:17:52.696Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-10-09T18:17:52.696Z",
    "id": 1
  }
]`

Now what I want to do is to display that data onto my homepage.ejs page.
my question is how do I do that, I would have expected something like this:

```
<%= model.user.name %>
```

which is obviously return an error. anything else I have tried just fails to work. I have looked all over sails's docs and got found nothing so I am really desperate.

Comment: show some code, especially where you're calling `res.render()`.

Comment: There is no code to show. I have created my API using blueprint which is using the address bar(sails feature) and I'm trying to understand how to get that data to my homepage EJS view.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data seems to be an array, my guess would be you need to use `model.user[0].name` or something similar.

Comment: you didn't get my question, I cannot access the server data. when I tried what you wrote its says model is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your object definition which is not accessible by your ejs code :

```
{"model" : { "user" : { "name": "Jonh", "createdAt": "2014-10-09T18:17:52.696Z", "updatedAt": "2014-10-09T18:17:52.696Z", "id": 1 } } }
```

With this structure from your API, you can access to the value with ejs engine :

```
<%= model.user.name %>
```

mscdex is right when he said this is an Array in your code.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my object because I didn't write any code building that API. also, I managed to get the API using a JSON Request. I just don't know how to get the data to my EJS file.